# Meaning of Trust Language

Tags: trusts-and-estates

Can someone interpret the meaning of the Trust articles in plain English? Is it a normal addition to a Trust?

[image: Trust Articles]

This is a second question about the same topic as another one of my questions but it is not a duplicate. I have edited the other questions to avoid any overlapping. I think the differences should be clear if you read them.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions you have already asked, especially when they are put on hold. Edit the previous question to make it on-topic.

Comment: Please read question more carefully it is not a duplicate and neither are answered.

Comment: While this clearly deals with the same trust as the other question (or at least a trust using the same language for 2 provisions) it does not seem to me to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 6.19 says that the trustee is not required to provide an accounting of the trust to anyone, even if the law says otherwise.

Section 6.20 says that **IF** the settlor (the person who established the trust) becomes incapacitated (unable to handle business, usually due to illness, injury, or age), then the trustee is required to provide an accounting to several people, specifically: 1) those people who will become beneficiaries of the trust when the settlor dies, 2) any person who may be acting as conservator of the estate, and 3) to any person who is acting as agent for the settlor  under the settlor's power of attorney to manage the settlor's property. (A conservator  is a person appointed, usually by a court, to manage an estate or property, so that it shall be in good order when it turned over to the proper owner. A conservator is often appointed when the owner is not able to manage his or her own property, or while a will is being settled.)

Section 6.20 also says that If the settlor becomes incapacitated the Trustee will give a copy of th trust document to the potential beneficiaries  (the same people indicated in item 1) above).

Section 6.20 seems to conflict with 6.19 and I have no idea how this conflict would be resolved. Other sections might make that clear, or the detailed law or case law might clarify that.